# Wrap Rails controller into Delayed Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, delayed-job

The gem named Delayed Job (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) can do many things in background. But can it run a Rails controller in background so that it still will respond to HTTP requests and return results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this would require Delayed Job to spin up a server. This does not work because a server is already running with your App.

What exactly are you trying to archive? If you have your Rails app running, it will be able to respond to HTTP requests that might come.

Comment: I need a solution to allow long waiting HTTP connections without blocking entire application.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem with a good webserver (e.g. Apache + Passenger)